# Array storage Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want my array of students to have their name and grade associated. So when I call on them after the fact I can display the top two performing students. This is homework So I don't need to have the whole code completed but I would like some help with making sure the inputs are properly stored. Right now my variables are `x` and `i`, `x` being the number of students, and `i` being the counter. Again my issues are with associating the grades of the students inputted with the names. I hope there is enough information.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please eneter how many students you have: ");
        x = in.nextInt();

        int students = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int grades[] = new int[x];
        String[] names = new String[x];

        for(i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter student name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine(); 
            names[i] = name;

            System.out.println("Grade: ");
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            grades[i] = grade;
            students++;
            sum += grade;
            x++;
        }

        if(students>0) {
            average = (double) sum/students;
        }
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
        System.out.println("There are " + students + " students");
        System.out.println("The top two students are: " + grades);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `java.util.Map` might help you here

Comment: Or you could sort the arrays to find the highest grades.

Comment: Hey! Have you considered creating a class `Student` with the fields `name` and `grade`?

Comment: @user looking into java.util.Map Thanks

Comment: As @akuzminykh pointed out it's better practise as per OOP's , make Class Student and then add each object to an Array or Arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the `for` loop will never end, as you keep increasing the value of `x`, which is also used in the end condition.

Here are some suggestions:

Just store the number of students when you read it and remove the `x` variable:

```
int students = in.nextInt();
int grades[] = new int[students ];
String[] names = new String[students ];
```

Then read in this number of sudents:

```
for(i = 0; i < students; i++) {
```

To find the top two students you'd use the following logic (assumes 2 or more students)

```
if grade[0] >= grade[1] 
  max1 = 0
  max2 = 1
else
  max1 = 1
  max2 = 0

for i from 2 to students-1
  if grade[i] >= grade[max1]
    max2 = max1
    max1 = i
  else if grade[i] > grade[max2]
    max2 = i
```

The top two students are then at positions `max1` and `max2` in the `names` and `grades` array.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill, but maybe someone will find it useful.

I store all the students in a `TreeSet`. I assume that each student has a unique name. I use a special `Comparator` to sort the students in the `TreeSet` according to their grades. A descending `Iterator` of the `TreeSet` will return the students from highest grade to lowest grade, so the first two items returned by this `Iterator` are the top two students.

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * A student name and her grade.
 */
public class StudentGrade {

    /** Name of student. */
    private String studentName;

    /** Grade for this student. */
    private int studentGrade;

    /**
     * Creates and returns instance of this class.
     * 
     * @param name  - student name
     * @param grade - student grade
     */
    public StudentGrade(String name, int grade) {
        studentName = name;
        studentGrade = grade;
    }

    /**
     * @return Student's name.
     */
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    /**
     * @return Student's rgade.
     */
    public int getStudentGrade() {
        return studentGrade;
    }

    /**
     * Two instances of this class are equal if they both have the same name.
     */
    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean isEqual = false;
        if (obj != null) {
            Class<?> objClass = obj.getClass();
            if (objClass.equals(getClass())) {
                StudentGrade other = (StudentGrade) obj;
                isEqual = studentName.equals(other.getStudentName());
            }
        }
        return isEqual;
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public int hashCode() {
        return studentName.hashCode();
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Object
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s [%d]", studentName, studentGrade);
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Stores all student grades, sorted by grade in ascending order.
        TreeSet<StudentGrade> studentSet = new TreeSet<>(new StudentGradeComparator());

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter how many students you have: ");
        int students = in.nextInt();
        int index = students;
        int sum = 0;
        while (index > 0) {
            // make sure we consume the newline character since 'nextInt()' does not
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("Enter grade for %s: ", name);
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            sum += grade;
            StudentGrade sg = new StudentGrade(name, grade);
            studentSet.add(sg);
            index--;
        }
        double average;
        if (students > 0) {
            average = (double) sum / students;
        }
        else {
            average = 0.0d;
        }
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
        String verb = students == 1 ? "is" : "are";
        String plural = students == 1 ? "" : "s";
        System.out.printf("There %s %d student%s.%n", verb, students, plural);
        if (students > 1) {
            Iterator<StudentGrade> iter = studentSet.descendingIterator();
            System.out.printf("The top two students are: %s, %s%n", iter.next(), iter.next());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Compares 'StudentGrade' instances according to their grades.
 */
class StudentGradeComparator implements Comparator<StudentGrade> {

    /**
     * Returns a positive number if 'sg1' grade is larger than that of 'sg2'.
     * Returns a negative number if 'sg1' grade is less than that of 'sg2'.
     * Returns zero if 'sg1' grade is equal to 'sg2' grade.
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(StudentGrade sg1, StudentGrade sg2) {
        if (sg1 == null) {
            if (sg2 != null) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (sg2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return sg1.getStudentGrade() - sg2.getStudentGrade();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample run:

```
Please enter how many students you have: 3
Enter student name: George
Enter grade for George: 70
Enter student name: Diego
Enter grade for Diego: 90
Enter student name: Edson
Enter grade for Edson: 65
The average is 75.0
There are 3 students.
The top two students are: Diego [90], George [70]
```